# why do we use pos in c++? assume by my code int pos = cHash(symbol);

Tags: c++, data-structures, hash, hashtable, theory

so I was doing a program of SymbolTable for my compiler course ....I landed with a problem of `pos` ...why do we use it on the first place? TIA <3

```
void insert(char *symbol, char *type)
{
    int pos = cHash(symbol);

    if (block[pos] == NULL)
    {
        block[pos] = new SymbolInfo();
        block[pos]->symbol = symbol;
        block[pos]->type = type;
        block[pos]->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        SymbolInfo *newNode = new SymbolInfo();
        newNode->symbol = symbol;
        newNode->type = type;

        // pointer swap
        SymbolInfo *nextNode = block[pos];
        block[pos] = newNode;
        newNode->next = nextNode;
    }
}
```

Comment: `pos` is the position within the array ...

Comment: Actually you don't have to use `pos` here because you can store and use a pointer or a reference to `block[cHash(symbol)]` instead of that.

Comment: You would need to ask the person teaching the course. We can’t say why a variable is used in a random function with no information about what’s going on.

Comment: I vote to close since there isn't enough context to answer. We don't know what `block` is. Assuming it's an array, then of course there needs to be some way to know which element to update, hence `[pos]`. There's certainly scope for reducing such repetition by factoring out to a function that takes a `MysteriousBlockType&` to which you pass `block[pos]` and thus only indexing once. But it's not clear whether your question is 'why index _at all_' or 'can I index _less_'.

Comment: Thank you all i understood the problem

Comment: my lecturer has given an assignment to make a symbol table, a symbol and the attribute type to input ... i already done most of the code just got stuck with the position...also this was my first ever question to stackoverflow ...so thank you all of you.

Answer (score 0):

The code here implements what’s called a chained hash table. We maintain an array of linked lists, and use the function cHash to assign each symbol to one of those linked lists.

The advantage of storing things this way is speed. If we put everything into a single linked list, then the average cost of looking something up is O(n), where n is the number of items in the list, since on average we have to look at at least half the items in the list. But by having multiple linked lists (say, b of them) and distributing items across them more or less randomly, we decrease the average cost of a lookup to O(1 + n/b), which is a lot faster if b is roughly the same order of magnitude as n.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no element in the chain then new element is added in front,
otherwise through hashing if we reach a chain or, bucket that contains an element then we insert the new element at the beginning of the chain and
the rest of the elements is linked to the end of new node.